# Nextjs Middleware not redirecting as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

_middleware not working as expected, i am trying to allow action when the route is a valid route based on if a token is stored or not, as well as monitor page access, the app is supposed to handle role management

```
validRoutes.push(`${base_url}/404`,`${base_url}/api/auth/user`,`${base_url}/api/auth/logout`,`${base_url}/api/auth/setpass`)

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
    const {cookies,url} = req;


    const jwt=cookies.user;

    if(url.includes(`${base_url}/login`)){
         console.log('if')
        if(jwt){
            return NextResponse.redirect(`${base_url}/`)
        }else{
            return NextResponse.next()
        }
    }
    else if(!url.includes(`${base_url}/login`)){
        if(jwt){
            if(validRoutes.includes(url)){
                return NextResponse.next()
            }
            return NextResponse.rewrite(`${base_url}/404`)
            
        }
        if(validRoutes.includes(url)){
            return NextResponse.next()
        }
        else{
         return NextResponse.redirect(`${base_url}/login`)
        }
        
    }
    else{
        return NextResponse.rewrite(`${base_url}/404`)
    }
    
 
    
  }
```

Comment: _"_middleware not working as expected"_ - can you describe its current faulty behaviour and how that's not expected?

Comment: So, I am checking if the user is logged in, and if user's is logged in, I compare the current url with the validRoutes, if current route is not in ValidRoutes user is sent to 404 page, yet even when the condition is true, it still skips the redirection